# Pull all the Contacts by Account name - SOQL

Tags: soql

I'm trying to pull the Contact field by Account name and I'm sure the way I'm doing must not be the right way.

my SOQL:

```
Select AccountId,Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone 
from Contact where Account__r.Name='BMW'
```

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:71 Didn't understand relationship 'Account__r'
>   in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be
>   sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please
>   reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Account is not a custom object, therefore your relationship name should be just 'Account'

```
Select AccountId,Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone 
from Contact where Account.Name='BMW'
```